# How to reuse ImageView after recycling its drawable?

Tags: android

I'm have gridview with many images, and I can show in this gridview different groups of images which can be changed by pressing some buttons. To prevent using big amount of memory I'm recycling all downloaded images after changing images group. Something like this:
My adapter loading images for views, and transfers them into views. After changing images group, I'm calling method recycleImages() to recycle all saved images

```
public class DataArrayAdapter<T extends View & DataListViewItem> extends ArrayAdapter<DataObject>
{

    //Loaded images. Key - position, value - image
    private SparseArray<Drawable> mImages;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        T view = (T) convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = createView(position);
        } else {
            //reuse view by transfering new data to it
            view.updateListViewItem(getItem(position));
        }

        checkViewImage(view, position);
        return view;
    }

    protected void checkViewImage(T view, int position) {
        if (view.needImage()) {
            if (mImages == null) {
                mImages = new SparseArray<Drawable>();
            }

            Drawable image = mImages.get(position);

            if (image == null) {
                String imageUrl = getItem(position).getUrl();

                if (imageUrl != null) {
                    //download image and put it to view after download
                    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(imageUrl, view);
                    imageRequest.send();
                }
            } else {
                view.setImageDrawable(image);
            }
        }
    }

    public void recycleImages() {
        if (mImages != null) {
            Drawable drawable;
            for (int i = 0, l = mImages.size(); i < l; ++i) {
                drawable = mImages.valueAt(i);
                if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                    ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap().recycle();
                }
            }
            mImages.clear();
        }
    }

}
```

Problem is that I'm reusing views and after recycling images I'm getting error:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot draw recycled bitmaps**
because old images are recycled but new images are not downloaded yet.
After recycling drawables I'm call setImageDrawable(null) for every imageView, that was used, but it doesn't help.
A big odd is that this error is not reproducing on tablet with Android 4.0.4 but it's reproduces on version 4.3 and higher.
How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**
ImageRequest is simple AsyncTask which creates object of ViewHolder class inside onPostExecute method and saves it in List. All this classes are in DataArrayAdapter

```
protected void onPostExecute(Drawable image) {
    mHolders.add(new ViewHolder(mView, image));
    checkLoaders();
}


private class ViewHolder {
    private T mView;
    private Drawable mImage;

    public ViewHolder(T view, Drawable image) {
        mView = view;
        mImage = image;
    }

    public void combine() {
        if (mView != null) {
            mView.setImageDrawable(mImage);
            mView = null;
            mImage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

method combine is called to all created ViewHolder objects, after loading all images, to draw all images at one moment

Comment: have you tried to use some placeholder bitmap instead of null while images are downloading?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't helps me

Comment: Could you share your `ImageRequest` code?

Comment: I'm edited my question